# Filling empty "B column" cells with last known value if rows have same "A column" value

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, data-science

Im really new to Python and Datascience.

I have a large Dataset(with 100K+ rows), in this dataset i have two columns `A` and `B`. `A` is a Datetime column and B is string.

Column B has some NaN values, i want to fill those NaN values with latest known B column value, given the condition that my empty B column row and already filled B column row are in the same day, month and year (Column A).

Lemme explain my Self:

Let's say that's my input:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A': ["2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-13 07:10:18", "2019-03-20 08:12:23", "2019-03-13 08:12:23", "2019-03-15 10:35:53", "2019-03-20 11:12:23"], 'B': ["B1", "B0", "B13", np.nan, "B10", "B12"]})
                     A    B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
1  2019-03-13 07:10:18   B0
2  2019-03-20 08:12:23  B13
3  2019-03-13 08:12:23  NaN
4  2019-03-15 10:35:53  B10
5  2019-03-20 11:12:23  B12
```

I want to fill the NaN value with B1(B value that occurs the same day and has the biggest time given the condition that this "Biggest time" isn't ahead of the actual `A` column value).

So my output should look like this:

```
                     A    B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
1  2019-03-13 07:10:18   B0
2  2019-03-20 08:12:23  B13
3  2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
4  2019-03-15 10:35:53  B10
5  2019-03-20 11:12:23  B12
```

I tried to achieve this with no success, the best i could do is making NaN Value to B13 using this :

```
df['B']=df['B'].replace({'B': {0: np.nan}}).ffill()
```

Can you please guys tell me what's the fatest and most economic way to achieve this?

Comment: Does it have to be same day only, or same day, month and year?

Comment: @rafaelc Same day, month and year

Comment: @Arès, can you please see comments in rafaelc's answer and clarify what you mean by "biggest time"? Does it mean the latest known time before the `NaN` is recorded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby`+`ffill`

```
as_date = pd.to_datetime(df.A)
s = np.argsort(as_date)

df['B'] = df.B.loc[s].groupby(as_date.loc[s].dt.date).ffill().loc[df.index]
```

---

```
                     A    B
0  2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
1  2019-03-13 07:10:18   B0
2  2019-03-20 08:12:23  B13
3  2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
4  2019-03-15 10:35:53  B10
5  2019-03-20 11:12:23  B12
```

Comment: This is requirement is certainly ambiguous. We don't know if we can fill with values _ahead of time_ (OP should clarify that). For example, if this a data frame with stock prices, you can't backfill a stock price from `10 AM` to `6 AM` since it wasn't known at that time

Comment: Thanks for chiming in guys ;}

Comment: Sorry for bumping this, but is there anyway to make it not only match rows with same year, month and day but with hour (only hour) too ? I tried with dt.time but apparently its taking the minutes and seconds in consideration too

Comment: @Arès USe `df.B.loc[s].groupby([as_date.loc[s].dt.date, as_date.loc[s].dt.hour]).ffill().loc[df.index]` or something among those lines

Comment: Thanks, you rock dude !

Answer (score 1):

Try `groupby().idxmax()`:

```
max_val = df.loc[df['A'].groupby(df['A'].dt.date).transform('idxmax'),'B'].values

df['B'] = np.where(df['B'].isna(), max_val, df['B'])
```

Output:

```
                    A    B
0 2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
1 2019-03-13 07:10:18   B0
2 2019-03-20 08:12:23  B13
3 2019-03-13 08:12:23   B1
4 2019-03-15 10:35:53  B10
5 2019-03-20 11:12:23  B12
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task can be performed with the following **one-liner**:

```
df.B = df.sort_values('A').groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.A).dt.date).B.ffill()
```

Comment: I corrected my initial solution, now the result is OK.